# Как в файле IDL правильно объявить константу

Tags: c++, delphi, c, com, idl

В определении интерфейса библиотеки COM мне нужны несколько констант которые можно было бы использовать после обработки файла IDL утилитами midl и tlibimp. То есть эти константы должны появиться в сгенерированных файлах *_i.h и *.pas чтобы их можно было использовать в программах на Си++ и Delphi соответсвенно.

Например, есть примерно такой файл:

```
[uuid(AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-00112233445566)]
library MyComLibrary
{
    const char * MY_SUPER_STR  = "TRO-LO-LO";
    const GUID   MY_SUPER_GUID = {   0xAAAAAAAA
                                  ,  0xBBBB
                                  ,  0xCCCC
                                  ,  0xDDDD
                                  , {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66}
                                 };

   // ...
}
```

Так вот, следов `MY_SUPER_STR` и `MY_SUPER_GUID` в сгенерированых MyComLibrary_i.h и MyComLibrary.pas я не обнаруживаю.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось объявить MY_SUPER_STR в IDL, только она появилась в .h файле как define.

```
interface Interface
{
    const char * MY_SUPER_STR  = "TRO-LO-LO";
...
```

В .h файле вот такой результат:

```
/* interface Interface */
/* [version][uuid] */ 

#define MY_SUPER_STR    ( "TRO-LO-LO" )
```

Также если вы хотите добавить целочисленные значения, то может пригодится enum.

Comment: Согласен, я проверил файлы внимательнее, действительно MIDL для простых типов генерит `#define`. Но что делать с массивами и структурами?

Comment: Да присваивание значения для массивов и структур IDL компилятор игнорирует. Но их можно объявить extern и добавить cpp файл в свой проект и инициализацией значений. Хотя возможно вы пытаетесь использовать idl не по назначению.